# Magento 1.9: sort grid view

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've added a column to my gridview and it suppose to show remaining days of an event.

```
$this->addColumn('calculate_days', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('myodule')->__('Remaining'),
            'type'      => 'options',
            'width'     => '200px',
            'options'   => $options,
            'frame_callback' => array($this, 'getRemaining'),  
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_calculateFilter')
        ));
```

`getRemaining` method:

```
 public function getRemaining($value, $row, $column)
    {
       // some calculation to find out remaining days based on some conditions

       return $days;
    }
```

If I don't specify the `index` key, clicking on the `Remaining` column does not work. So I've added `index` key to `addColumn` like bellow:

```
$this->addColumn('calculate_days', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('myodule')->__('Remaining'),
            'type'      => 'options',
            'width'     => '200px',
            'index'     => 'created_at',
            'options'   => $options,
            'frame_callback' => array($this, 'getRemaining'),  
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_calculateFilter')
        ));
```

now the sort is WORK but not correctly. when I specify the `index`, sort applied by `index` column(in this case will sort by `created_at`) but I want to sort by remaining days.

what should I do to solve this problem? or is there any `sort callback`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add this value as a new field in this grid? And then update this field values each day by a cronjob.

Then you will have in a native way the items sorted and also you avoid to recalculate each value each time you filter o see this grid.

Hope it helps,
Regards